# Need little help incomplete implementation error in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting an "incomplete implementation" error in my .m file, but I cannot figure it out how to fix it. I`ll post .h and .m files if you can give me tips on how to fix that. Thanks.

Apparently, I need to put more details, or I cannot post the question because the post contains mostly code, so this are just some dummy lines.

**.h File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BlogViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
- (IBAction)selectPicturePressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)blogPost:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *commentTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;


@end
```

**.m File**

```
#import "BlogViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

@interface BlogViewController ()

-(void)showErrorView:(NSString *)errorMsg;

@end

@implementation BlogViewController **//Incomplete Implementation**

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;
@synthesize username = _username;
@synthesize commentTextField = _commentTextField;
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste all your code? You're missing a `@end` at the end of your .m file, and I'm wondering if anything else is missing.

Comment: The basic answer to your question, though, is that it looks like you declared but didn't implement the `selectPicturePressed:` and `blogPost:` methods.

Comment: It should not be error, but it should be warning

Comment: @godel9 It could very easily be methods from the `protocol` this class is conforming to, and if he ctrl+dragged the IBActions from interface builder, the methods would've been generated for him automatically in the `.m`

Comment: @nhgrif I missed the protocols the first time I read the post, but I just checked, and there aren't any non-optional methods for any of the three protocols listed.

Comment: I also just noticed he has a `@interface` in the `.m`

Comment: Could you please show the error messages? double check in your NIb file that selectPicturePressed and blogPost are present as you would get a compiler error if there still linked but have bee removed!

Comment: No, Its not the whole code, but found the answer to my question. it was:

- (IBAction)blogPost:(id)sender {
    // and here
}

missing, after adding it fixe the problem straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBActions are just regular functions with syntactic sugar for connecting them to interface builder therefore you have to implement them in the .m file

**.m file:**

```
- (IBAction)selectPicturePressed:(id)sender {
    // code here
}
- (IBAction)blogPost:(id)sender {
    // and here
}
```

Comment: Thank you Max, I missed 
- (IBAction)blogPost:(id)sender {
    // and here
}

That fixed the problem straight away :)

Answer (score 1):

On the line that's giving you the `Incomplete Implementation` error, you can get more details about what you're missing.

You don't paste all your `.m` so it's anyone's guess what you're missing, however, your `.h` declares 2 methods and 3 protocols that you must implement.

Your `.m` file must have method bodies for these two methods:

```
- (IBAction)selectPicturePressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)blogPost:(id)sender;
```

Likely, you already have these in here, particularly if these were generated by Ctrl+Dragging from interface builder.

---

But you must also include, at a minimum, all the required methods from the protocols you declared.

- [`UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html)
- [`UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
- [`UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol official documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html)

(I'm not completely familiar with these protocols and don't know for sure that they actually have any `@required` methods.)

---

Your `.m` also has a private interface, which declares a method you must implement in the `implementation`.

```
-(void)showErrorView:(NSString *)errorMsg;
```

You declared this method in a private interface, so be sure to implement this method as well.

---

Regardless of what you're missing, Xcode will absolutely tell you if you just click on the error/warning.  Xcode will give you the names of the methods its expecting to find in your implementation but cannot.